# Other's edits shouldn't be shown if the questioner over-edits them within the grace period

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, grace-period

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestion: block edits by others in the 5 minute window after creating a post or doing an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26184/suggestion-block-edits-by-others-in-the-5-minute-window-after-creating-a-post-or)

### Please close this question - i found a superior one on the metanet.

**Question to root for:** [Suggestion: block edits by others in the 5 minute window after creating a post or doing an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26184/suggestion-block-edits-by-others-in-the-5-minute-window-after-creating-a-post-or)

---

Please don't show the edits others made to answers within the 5-minutes window if the questioner saw the edits and overwrote them. To summarize:

> Don't show the edit label if the last edit was made by the owner within the grace period.

I think this is what many people believe is already the case - but actually (apparently without reason), it is not.

**Edit:** Originally this question ignored the fact that you want to see other's edits. So the new revision requires the original poster to have over-edited it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46078/quick-edits-force-a-badly-formatted-post-to-wiki-within-minutes

Comment: Re your edit: The edited label already reflects the time of the revision, even if you edit further within the grace period. (This applies to other people's edits, and self-edits.)

Comment: @Jon i don't want to make the edits reflect the time, but i want them to be not shown at all... Also after some time passes, the edits don't show the precise time of an edit - so you can't see whether the edit was within 5mins or not in a first glance.

Comment: Though I don't fully agree with what you're asking (I think the revision history *should* show all authors), +1 for NOT showing the name of some intermediate editor (as being *the last* editor) when the original poster has changed the post after that. If indeed currently "X" is shown as the last editor when OP posts, X edits, OP edits again, then that's A MAJOR BUG, in my opinion! (As an aside, note that the tooltips always show the exact time.)

Comment: @Arjan thanks dude xD Why the downvotes, folks

Comment: @litb Welcome to Meta. On meta, downvotes mean "I don't think this feature should be implemented" as opposed to "Bad question". See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-work for more info.

Comment: @Arjan I believe that the OP will be shown as the last editor. The grace period applies **only if** there were no intervening editors.

Comment: @waiwai933 and litb, but then the question is meaningless? Maybe we should test this, like [here in the Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/55865#55865)?

Comment: @Arjan well, my question wants that the grace period continues but shows the last editor unless that editor was the question owner. Or alternatively to implement your suggestion to block edits during the first grace period, which humbly seems to be the better idea since it seems to be easier to implement.

Comment: @Arjan therefor i'm now rooting for this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26184/suggestion-block-edits-by-others-in-the-5-minute-window-after-creating-a-post-or and want to close my one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with others that showing *who* wrote *what* is very important. Hence, I'd rather have one of the following:

1. Disable the edit option for others, during *the first* grace period.

   or
2. End the grace period of the previous editor once someone else has submitted an edit. (A new grace period starts for whoever edited last.)

As for 1), I never edit any post while it's not 5 minutes old yet. And as for 2), I would actually expect the grace period to work like that already, but apparently it's not?

Prematurely ending a grace period *might* evolve in some edit wars though, targeting folks who are known to answer quickly to be "first", and only then enhance their post a lot within the (expected) grace period. Editing by others will then reveal that, but the post will still be first, so I doubt it matters. (And I don't even known if the fastest gun in the west [is actually a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27035/using-a-quick-post-to-get-the-top-then-editing/27053#27053).)

Comment: Yep i agree. But this is a more radical change than simply not showing edits in the grace period, in my opinion.

Comment: @litb, not showing an intermediate editor seems a more radical change to me :-) (Note that I changed my answer a bit -- litb's "I agree" might not apply any more.)

Answer (score 11):

Disagree...  If someone goes in and changes my post at all, I want to know about it.  I'm the one who gets to look like an idiot if they screwed with it and their user name is not visible as having edited it...

Answer (score 4):

**All users should always be able to determine whether the person who's listed as the poster actually said what's attributed to him or her.**

Otherwise, you invite all sorts of potential abuse that would require mod attention, but doesn't today because the community can self police.

Answer (score 0):

Umm..

> Don't show the edit label if the last
>   edit was made by the owner within the
>   grace period.

Isn't this already implemented?

EDIT:

I just edited this question within the 5 minute window and no edit thing appeared...

Comment: But if i edit your answer 1 min after you post, then you edit 2 min after post, it shows your edit, even though it is still technically in the grace period.

Comment: -1 No this isn't implemented...

Comment: @Justin, are you saying that *your* name would be shown as the last editor if Earlz posts, you edit, and Earlz edits again within 5 minutes of the original post? If so, then that's a bug, if you'd ask me?

Comment: Aha, @Justin, it seems you're actually saying Earlz will be listed as the last editor, and the revision history will probably show Earlz, you and Earlz again? (I assume it was Earlz who wrote "I just edited this question within the 5 minute window and no edit thing appeared"?)

Comment: @Arjan yep it was Earlz who edited it.